# Update javascript through asp.net for multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched everywhere to do the below necessary function

I want to replicate the function on asp.net application (VB), and it works perfectly only for a single image, but now i'm try to do it for multiple images, but really dont know how to go about it and stuck with the problem for the last 2 days, searching through stack and other forums.

I prefer this approach, because not much variables to call and have to only insert the image tags, this is what i believe

Below the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg1" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

if you see, i have added another line

```
<img id="myImg1" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
```

also in the styles section

```
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
```

works only for 1 image

I really dont know how to call the function in the code behind in asp.net (VB), since my skills for Jquery is at the bottomline.

I have searched everywhere, but to all in vain

Please help

Comment: it's completely unclear what you're asking for can you please elaborate more..

Comment: Hi there, its about the modal image, try this link, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img trying to achieve for multiple images

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve.? You're placing 2 images in code but there is only one image in your example from w3schools did you mean that how to change image ID for front on the basis of logic implemented at back end.?

Comment: i have taken that example from w3schools and would like to implement for 2 images as the code pasted above. I dont know how to call the functionality so that when the image is clicked it pops up. the w3schools link works for 1 image correctly, I would like to add multiple images so that it can do the same function for them too

Comment: Ok so you want to make it working for multiple images right.?

Comment: @user1753985 Please find [this fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMCUUE7CMU2)

Comment: Check answer. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming i got your point , you are trying to apply class to the image tag but you have multiple imags so in css instead of going with `id` go with a custom `classname`

Ex: change styles as follows

```
.customImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.customImg :hover {opacity: 0.7;}
```

In your aspx markup add style as follows

```
<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" class="customImg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg1" src="img_fjords.jpg" class="customImg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
```

Comment: Your problem is not in CSS but you want to change image ID for modal right.? Using Jquery.

Comment: @user1753985 please tell me what exactly you looking for, did my assumption is right?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give same class to all `Img` tags and than loop though it and bind click event for all of these using [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

For particular your case please find [FIDDLE](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMCUUE7CMU2).

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('customclass');

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption


var img = document.getElementById('myImg2');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('MyImages');

var myFunction = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
img[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" class="MyImages" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg2" class="MyImages" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Check this Code it will work for both of your images.

Comment: what if i have hundreds of images and i have to write a click function on all of those? I don't recommend to write the a same code repeatedly do u?

Comment: @Curiousdev No I'd not. Sorry for the mistake. In such case I'll write a generalise function which will handle all of those images. Here my answer was posted in hurry and that's the reason behind mistake. :)

Comment: ohh that's completely fine happens sometimes @user1753985 would you please accept this answer for future references as well ??

Answer (score -1):

**the following code can change opacity for multiple images , check out the way i hav given the class names**

```css
.image {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg1" class="image one" src="http://www.lonestardigital.com/EOS_D30/Sample_Pix/D30_Img_3771(400x400_Crop).jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg2" class="image two" src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_68155_400x400.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you CuriosDev for the help, below is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg"  class="customclass" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg1" class="customclass" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
debugger;
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('customclass');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var myFunction = function(){
debugger;
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post answers this way. You can either accept others answers. if you're finding anything different in my answer then you can surely post your own answer. But this way you're flooding site by your own questions and answers.